# can asset folder be accessed by the user when the apk is installed?

Tags: android, apk

For example i have an **android program which contains important files** in the **assets folder** , can the user who installed the apk access the assets folder or not ? for hacking purpose

Comment: Is this an assets folder provided by LibGDX?

Comment: for example you have an installed app on android , can the user access the file inside the assets folder ? is that still unclear ?

Comment: Yes, it still is. If the user were to change the extension of the apk to ".zip," they could access everything inside of the apk, including the assets folder packaged with the application installed.

Comment: thank you Selvin  and Filzeet  i just got the answer

Comment: for all intent and purposes, you should consider that anything put anywhere in the apk is compromised.

Comment: This is why you should rely on the Play Store installation. So that only rooted users will be able to access the folders of your installed app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone can open your .apk just by changing the extension to .rar, what you can do to protect your code is releasing it using proguard rules, but still in that case an image for instance in the drawable folder  can be compromised, however an string in your strings.xml is bit more protected.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can decompile your app and can see a lot of things including your assets. .apk file is just an compressed file which can be extracted easily.